# Loading images does not load them into memory

Tags: actionscript-3, memory, bitmap, bitmapdata

I am loading a batch of 150 HD images into my app - it is basically a 3D view of an object. Once I load the image files using `Loader` instances I store the loaders' first child's bitmapdata in a Vector. When all of the loaded, I want to begin to "rotate" the object = meaning I am simply swapping the images. I take the Vector where I have the bitmapdatas and draw them onto a canvas bitmapdata one after the other. No science there, it all works as intended.

The problem is that once all the images are loaded and stored in a vector and BEFORE they are drawn to the canvas, they are not in the memory. That means that the first rotation of my 3D object (-> all 150 images drawn) is really slow. After the first rotation there is no problem and all is fluid. My question is: is there a way to force the images to get loaded into the memory without drawing them onto the stage? I expected that they would simply get loaded to memory once they are loaded to the app (Wrong!).

I tried to use addChild() instead of drawing them to a canvas bitmap, same result. I don't think the code is necessary but just in case:

```
private var _loaders:Vector.<Loader>;
private static const NAME:String = "img_00";
private static const MIN:uint = 0;
private static const MAX:uint = 150;
private var _loaded:uint = 0;
private var _currentFrameIndex:uint = 0;
private var _canvas:Bitmap;
private var _bitmaps:Vector.<BitmapData>;
private var _destPoint:Point;

public function loadImages():void {
    var s:String;
    for(var i:int=MIN; i<=MAX; i++) {
        if(i < 10) s = "00" + i;
        else if(i < 100) s = "0" + i;
        else s = i.toString();
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadHandler);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadHandler);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, loadHandler);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("images/JPEG/"+ NAME + s + ".jpg"));
        _loaders.push(loader);
    }
}

private function loadHandler(e:Event):void {
    _loaded++;

    if(_loaded > (MAX - MIN)) {
        _bitmaps = new Vector.<BitmapData>(_loaders.length);
        for(var i:int=0; i<_loaders.length; i++) {
            var loader:Loader = _loaders[i];
            _bitmaps[i] = Bitmap(loader.getChildAt(0)).bitmapData;
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, loadHandler);
        }
        setFrame(0);
        dispatchEvent(new Event(LOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
}

public function setFrame(frame:uint):void {
    if(frame >= 0 && frame < _bitmaps.length) {
        _currentFrameIndex = frame;
        var bmpData:BitmapData = _bitmaps[_currentFrameIndex];
        _canvas.bitmapData.copyPixels(bmpData, bmpData.rect, _destPoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not in the memory" means that the images are loaded, but not yet decoded, and this decode is done on the fly, and this takes the time you observe as slowness. You can attempt to "virtually" rotate the image by having a bitmap that's not yet added to stage to be the reference to each of the bitmapDatas of your vector. Make a progress bar that shows how much of the vector has already been decoded, and once this happens, display the bitmap and give the user smooth rotation.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,prerender);
var b:Bitmap=new Bitmap();
/* optional
    b.x=stage.stageWidth;
    b.y=stage.stageHeight;
    addChild(b);
*/
var vi:int=0;
var sh:Shape=new Shape();
sh.graphics.lineStyle(4,0,1); // a simple progress bar
sh.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
sh.graphics.lineTo(100,0);
sh.scaleX=0;
sh.x=stage.stageWidth/2-50; // centered by X
sh.y=stage.stageHeight/2;
addChild(sh);
function prerender(e:Event):void {
    if (vi==_bitmaps.length) {
        // finished prerender
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, prerender);
        removeChild(sh);
        // removeChild(b); if optional enabled
        setFrame(0);
        return;
    }
    b.bitmapData=_bitmaps[vi];
    vi++;
}
```

Also, it's always better to assign the `bitmapData` property to a `Bitmap` object if you don't plan to have that bitmapdata changed. So, instead of your `_canvas.bitmapData.copyPixels(bmpData, bmpData.rect, _destPoint);` you just do `_canvas.bitmapData = bmpData;` and it'll work.

UPDATE: Your issue might as well nail to the last point, that is assigning instead of copying. If your `destPoint` is something else than (0,0), you just make another `Bitmap` object on top of your `_canvas` with desired offset, and assign bitmapdatas in there. I have remembered that when I first made multiple animated objects based on a single `Vector.<BitmapData>` like yours, and tried doing `copyPixels()`, my animations were jittering and not displaying proper frames, but once I did `_bitmap.bitmapData=_bitmaps[currentFrame]` everything went as smooth as it should be.

Comment: I was guessing it was exactly that - the images not decoded yet (would explain the memory usage and the slowness as well). Well, too bad, I guess the user will have to wait a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: PS: the render bitmap MUST be on the display list and it MUST be visible. Otherwise it won't work, so seems like the addChild/removeChild is not optional in this case. (so it could just be rendered on the main canvas).

Comment: Interesting. Okay, I'm glad you've got it.